# SOLR 6.1 tail: cannot open 'solr-6.1.0/server/logs/solr.log

Tags: solr

I cannot start solr 6.1 server with the "solr start" command due to an error about non-existing logs directory. There are relevant threads here which suggest upgrading to java 1.8, but I am already using java 1.8 and that does not solve my problem. I wonder if anyone knows how to solve this?

Details:

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.04; Solr: 6.1
```

Start-up commands tried (all getting the same error):

```
sudo ./bin/solr start
sudo ./bin/solr start -p 8984
```

Error message in the console:

```
Solr listening on 8983 after 30 seconds!
tail: cannot open '/home/zqz/Work/solr-6.1.0/server/logs/solr.log' for reading: No such file or directory
```

Error log in the file:  server/logs/solr-8983-console.log

```
org.eclipse.jetty.start.graph.GraphException: Unable to register 
module: ${jetty.base}/modules/._http.mod
org.eclipse.jetty.start.graph.GraphException: Unable to register 
module: ${jetty.base}/modules/._http.mod
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Modules.registerModule(Modules.java:205)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Modules.registerAll(Modules.java:186)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.processCommandLine(Main.java:293)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:74)

Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:281)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:339)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Module.process(Module.java:282)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Module.<init>(Module.java:103)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Modules.registerModule(Modules.java:200)
... 3 more

Usage: java -jar start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
   java -jar start.jar --help  # for more information
```

My java config:

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-0ubuntu1.16.04.2-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: My initial guess would be that the server log isn't being created because you have an error that barfs out before log creation happens (the tail call is an error external to Solr itself).  Your problem is the description from the console log. I'd try re-extracting the most recent version of Solr (maybe your disk filled up while extracting?)

Comment: well with a fresh download it works, but I had to migrate some parts of my schema. no idea why they previous version wouldnt work

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem with a custom package of solr.
The files started with ._ are generated by Mac OS.
I've just re-package the folder after set this environment variable:
    COPYFILE_DISABLE=1